# My player prefab moves forward fine until it hits an object, what is going on?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, move

I'm making a unity game based off of TierZoo, and while testing a movement script, i crashed into one of the rigidbody trees for fun... and that made the player prefab stop moving forward, and it started moving in odd directions Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewPlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public GameObject player;
    public float thrust = 1.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(player.transform.right * thrust * 2.5f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) { player.transform.Rotate(0, -1, 0); }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) { player.transform.Rotate(0, 1, 0); }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            rb.AddRelativeForce(player.transform.right * thrust * -2.5f);
        }
    }
}
```

If you can find a way to fix this, let me know.

Comment: When you say odd. Define odd

Comment: did the player object maybe rotate due to the impact and thus `player.transform.right` is rotating along with it?

Comment: @BugFinder Like moving sideways or backward.

Comment: @derHugo It might be possible, also my prefab has x and z rotation disabled

Comment: so maybe it is rotating around Y then? ;) I mean because of the collision not the one it does anyway in your script

Comment: @derHugo That's how the a and d rotation system works

Comment: @derHugo oof i did not think about that last part of the comment when i posted it

Comment: yeah but it seems that you get some additional rotations you don't want to get .. also note that the code you have is very bad for two reasons: When `Rigidbody` is involved then don't do movements in `Update` and through `transform`! This breaks the physics. Rather in `FixedUpdate` and through the `rb` e.g. using `MovePosition` and `MoveRotation`.  Second you are moving and rotating framereate-dependent by fixed steps of 1 or `thrust * 2.5f` .. rather use `Time.deltaTime` to convert these values from Unit/frame to Unit/second: `rb.MoveRotation(Vector3.up * ANGLEPERSECOND * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: you should handle UserInput (`Update`) and Physics (`FixedUpdate`) separately

Comment: @derHugo can you post the fixed script? I'm still a noob when it comes to real programming (however im pretty good at coding on scratch.mit.edu)

Answer (score 0):

You could fix the rotation also in Y direction by keeping track of it and setting it hard in `FixedUpdate`.

In general as said in the comments:

Whenever a `Rigidbody` is involved you should **not**

- do movements through the `transform` component
- do movements in `Update`

both breaks the physics engine and you might get strange and unexpected movements or simply no collisions working etc.

Rather do
 - go through the `Rigidbody` component e.g. using `MovePosition` and [`MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html)
 - do these in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

these keeps the physics intact and moves your `Rigidbody` only e.g. until it collides meanwhile.

Then for the rotation you have **framerate-dependent** values `Rotate(0, -1, 0)`! You rather want to use [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) in order to get smooth **framerate-independent** rotation speed - not in 1 degree per frame but rather e.g. 45 degrees per second.

You script could look like

```
public class NewPlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    // already reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;
    public GameObject player;
    public float thrust = 1.0f;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // as fallback get it on runtime
        if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    bool moveLeft;
    bool moveRight;
    bool rotateLeft;
    bool rotateRight;

    private float angle;

    void Update()
    {
        // Get User input here 
        // (in your case it would be also fine to do it in FixedUpdate.
        //  What doesn't work in FixedUpdate are mainly the one-time events like GetKeyDown)
        moveRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W);
        rotateLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A);
        rotateRight = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D);
        moveLeft = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S); 
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(moveRight) rb.AddRelativeForce(rb.rotation * Vector3.right * thrust * 2.5f);
        if(moveLeft) rb.AddRelativeForce(rb.rotation * Vector3.right * thrust * -2.5f);

        // Now for the rotations keep track of what you rotated already
        // and overwrite the rotation with the fix value:
        if(rotateLeft)
        {
            // e.g. for rotating 45°/second
            angle -= -45 * Time.deltaTime; 
            rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0));
        }
        if(rotateRight)
        {
            angle += 45 * Time.deltaTime; 
            rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, angle, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still exists, when i bump into something the forward movement vector stops facing the right direction and i end up moving the wrong way. I'd suggest adding more things that are relative to the prefab, not the world.

Comment: You're right totally forgot to fix the issue ^^ Only concentrated on the suggested refactoring part, sorry ^^ Updated